# _mm_cvt_ss2si gives different results than simple rounding

Tags: c, sse, rounding

In the code below, method A differs from method B.  Can someone explain
why _mm_cvt_ss2si rounds to even number when decimal part is exactly 0.5 ?

```
float f;

// rounding method  A
_mm_cvt_ss2si(_mm_load_ss(&f));

// rounding method B
(long)((f>0.0f) ? (f + 0.5f):(f -0.5f));
```

Comment: Round-to-even is the default for IEEE.

Comment: When the number to be rounded is exactly halfway, the rounding mode in MXCSR register comes into play. That applies to ordinary FP operations (add, multiply,..) and I think it applies to this operation too. The default mode is to round the 'midway' numbers to the nearest even result. I can't find any good info on how it actually works, but you could try changing those bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments for the answer to your question.

If you want a specific rounding mode in one case, without changing the MXCSR, you can use SSE4.1 `ROUNDPD / ROUNDPS`.  (This doesn't do an integer conversion, just rounds the FP value to an integer.)

```
__m128d _mm_round_pd (__m128d a, int rounding)
```

See the manuals for what flags you can pass as a `rounding` arg.